# Copy constructor initialize a reference member in initialization list causes dangling pointer

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor

I have a class A with a reference member `num`. And I have written a copy constructor that initialize `num` in the initialization list. But the outcome seems strange, shouldn't the printed out value be 100? And when did my program modified the value of `a.num` and `aa.num`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int& num;
    A(int n):num(n){}
    A(const A& obj):num(obj.num){}

    void print(){
        cout << num << endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    A a(100);
    A aa = a;
    a.print();  //Expected to be 100, but it isn't
    aa.print(); //Also expected to be 100, but it isn't

    //The address of a.num and aa.num are the same, so both of them are referencing to the same place. But the question is why the value isn't 100 but a strange value
    cout << &(a.num) << " " << &(aa.num) <<endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
-1077613148
-1077613148
0xbfc4ed94 0xbfc4ed94
```

Comment: [Clang warns about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7IJQd9)

Comment: "I have a class A with a reference member". That's your problem right here.

Answer (score 5):

The issue has nothing to do with copy constructor. In the constructor `A::A(int n)`, you're binding the member reference `num` to the constructor parameter `n`, which will be destroyed when get out of the constructor, left the reference `num` dangled. Any dereference on it leads to UB.

You might change the constructor to taking a reference,

```
A(int& n):num(n){}
```

then use it like

```
int i = 100;
A a(i);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bYqUB8c5w6cpB5NR)

Comment: Wow, you are genius! That solves my problem! Thanks so much